# What is the point of creating both AbstractStringBuilder and StringBuilder?

Tags: java, stringbuilder

Why did Java developers didn't create one class, `AbstractStringBuilder` and rename it to `StringBuilder`?

e.g., the method in `AbstractStringBuilder`:

```
public AbstractStringBuilder append(double d) {
    FloatingDecimal.appendTo(d,this);
    return this;
}
```

and the method in `StringBuilder`:

```
@Override
public StringBuilder append(double d) {
    super.append(d);
    return this;
}
```

I suppose we can keep only one method in `AbstractStringBuilder` and it will work fine. What's the point of creating the useless wrapper `StringBuilder`?

Comment: Short answer: So `StringBuffer` could extend it, too.

Comment: Abstract classes are generally created to provide a base from which other implementations can extend from without the need to provide a lot of boiler plate or duplicated code. It's possible the the append(double) method in StringBuilder was implemented different to begin with and was changed over time

Comment: AFAIK, `StringBuffer` came first, and then they wanted to add `StringBuilder`. So they probably moved all the code from `StringBuffer` into `AbstractStringBuilder`, then made it extend it, and then made `StringBuilder` extend it too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `AbstractStringBuilder` is not a `public class`, short of asking the developers why they wrote it, one can only speculate...

**Speculation**

Note that `StringBuffer`,

> A thread-safe, mutable sequence of characters.

was added in 1.0. `StringBuilder`'s Javadoc reads

> A mutable sequence of characters. This class provides an API compatible with `StringBuffer`, but with no guarantee of synchronization. **This class is designed for use as a drop-in replacement for `StringBuffer` in places where the string buffer was being used by a single thread (as is generally the case)**. Where possible, it is recommended that this class be used in preference to `StringBuffer` as it will be faster under most implementations.

(emphasis mine) and was added in 1.5. The idea is that this class is an improvement upon `StringBuffer` in most cases, but is overall very similar in functionality (can replace each other). As noted by @immibis and @MadProgrammer in the comments, the idea of inheritance saves a lot of trouble in cases where you want similar functionality.

I found one simple example in the method `append(String`). In `StringBuilder`, it is

```
@Override
public StringBuilder append(String str) {
    super.append(str);
    return this;
}
```

In `StringBuffer` it is

```
@Override
public synchronized StringBuffer append(String str) {
    toStringCache = null;
    super.append(str);
    return this;
}
```

and in `AbstractStringBuilder` it is

```
public AbstractStringBuilder append(String str) {
    if (str == null)
        return appendNull();
    int len = str.length();
    ensureCapacityInternal(count + len);
    str.getChars(0, len, value, count);
    count += len;
    return this;
}
```

What we see is that the only difference between the thread-safe and not thread-safe versions is some cache control (`toStringCache`), but they both call the same method in their superclass, hence reusing code through inheritance.

**Analogy**

Think of it as if you are the one writing code. You create a class `dog` which includes the anatomical structure of a dog (ears, tail, 4 legs...) and methods related to its action, like `bark`. After 5 years you want to create a class `cat` to represent a cat. Would you start from scratch? No, you would create an `abstract class FourLeggedAnimal` with the structure of ears, tail, 4 legs etc., and with the method `makeSound`. You will then extends this class and use all those similarities in both subclasses, overriding when necessary (`bark` and `meow`).

Asking

> What's the point of creating the useless wrapper StringBuilder?

will be the same as someone asking you

> What's the point of creating the useless wrapper Cat?

Comment: The key idea in that very-good answer is ... *"after five years* you now want to."  (And, you want to do it without breaking tons of existing code and/or forcing all of it to be re-validated.  You didn't write the original code.  The guy who did got smooshed by a bread-truck. You have very little time in which to get this done reliably.)  The abstract-class didn't previously exist, because it wasn't necessary.  Adding it, specifically as a junction-point for implementing `cat`, is a very safe way to graft-on the new functionality in such *(legacy ...)* programs.

Comment: @MikeRobinson Very true, although even if you did write the original class and you have a lot of time, it would still be the right approach (or at least *a* right approach). It is not always the case though in other JDK areas, unfortunately.